# Add margin dynamically to any found occurrence

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I make it more elegant and universal? It works but I would like to have the margin added +52px to every next .alert occurrence.

```
var alerts = $(".alert");
if(alerts.is(":visible")) {
    if(alerts.length > 1 ) {
        alerts.eq(1).css('margin-top', '52px');
        alerts.eq(2).css('margin-top', '104px');
        alerts.eq(3).css('margin-top', '156px');
    }
    alerts.delay(5000).slideUp("slow");
}
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This :

```
 $(".alert:visible").css('margin-top', function(i){return 52*i+'px'})
    .delay(5000).slideUp("slow");
```

Comment: really good destroy! thanks! ... but it adds 52px to the first occurrence as well. Any way to void that?